# how to migrate search query from ElasticsearchRepository to ElasticsearchOperations

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

My repository class uses the queries by using the standard method name *findByxxx*. It also has custom query using *NativeSearchQueryBuilder*.

Since search() methods have been removed from ElasticsearchRepository, I will create corresponding class to use ElasticsearchOperations. My code is like below.

```
    @Repository
    public interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {
    
         public Optional<Book> findById(String bookId);

        //default public Page<Book> fetchBooksForUser(String userId, Pageable pageable) {...}
    }
    
    @Service
    public class BookOperation{   //new class
    
        @Autowired
        private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;
    
        public Page<Book> fetchBooksForUser(String userId, Pageable pageable) {..use elasticsearchOperations...}
    }
    
    @Service
    public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    
        @Autowired
        private BookRepository bookRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        private BookOperation bookOperation;
    
        //some methods use bookRepository, some methods use formsPackageOperation
    }
```

I have more than 20 Repository classes. I don't want to repeat this 20 times. Is there a better to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a repository fragment, check tyhe documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations.

In the interface you define the method you need and in the `Impl` file you implement the necessary logic - you can just inject an `ElasticsearchOperations` into the implementations class.

As for the changes in your existing repositories: You just need to add your custom interface to the  `implements` clause.